# routes laravel with a variable

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Hello this is my controller:

```
public function getValues(Request $request){
    $typ=$request->get('typ');
    $stellentyp=$request->get('stellentyp');
    $bereich=$request->get('bereich');
    $view = 'user.'.$stellentyp;
    return view($view,['typ' => $typ, 'stellentyp', $stellentyp, 'bereich', $bereich]);
}
```

I want that the user can select a "stellentyp" and then the view with that "stellentyp" should be shown.

But I have a problem with my routes, they do not know the variable "stellentyp". 
 How can I connect my controller with my routes?

I tried this

```
Route::post('user/{$stellentyp}', 'StartController@getValues')->name('user.{$stellentyp}');
```

but it does not work :(.  The error is:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: user] [URI:
>   user/{$stellentyp}]. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\j4ylara\resources\views\user\start.blade.php)

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: user] [URI: user/{$stellentyp}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\j4ylara\resources\views\user\start.blade.php)

this is the error

Comment: You might want to read https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters

Comment: Make sure you put everything in the question, not in the comments.  You can edit a question you already posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get it :D

```
<form action="{{ action('StartController@getValues') }}" method="post" id="postData">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<select name="stellentyp">
    <option value="praktika">Praktika</option>
    <option value="fwd">Freiwilligendienste</option>
    <option value="jobs">Ferien- und/oder Nebenjobs</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Jetzt finden</button>
```

this is my blade.php

and my controller is the same and my routes looks like this

```
Route::resource('user/start', 'StartController');
Route::post('user/angebote', 'StartController@getValues');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post('user/{stellentyp}', 'StartController@getValues')->name('user.values');
```

In order to add a variable inside the route path you don't have to use the dollar signal to declare it. Check above code. Also the name of the route does not have to be dynamically assigned.

Answer (score 0):

in laravel routes you don't need $ sign for variable
, remove $ sign and test your route again, it should be work...

```
Route::post('user/{stellentyp}', 'StartController@getValues')->name('user.stellentyp');
```

and add $stellentype to your controller method input like that:

```
public function getValues(Request $request,$stellentype)
```

Answer (score 0):

Route parameter totaly different from POST parameters.

when you send a post parameter, it should be in your form as a input or selectbox etc.. then you can catch them in controller with `get()` method from $request (instance of Request class)

```
public function getValues(Request $request){
    $request->get("post")
}
```

But route parameter not send in a form, we send them with below way

in blade file

```
<form action="{{route("user.values",$user_id)}}">
```

in route file

```
Route::post('user/{id}', 'StartController@getValues')->name('user.{$stellentyp}');
```

and catch them in controller as a function parameter

```
public function getValues(Request $request,$user_id){
    dd($user_id);
}
```

Comment: i send the post parameter and catch it in my controller and store it in a variable called $stellentyp. and now i want when i select a "Stellentyp" it shows me this view: www.test/$stellentyp.com like this but i dont know

Comment: should i pass the parameter in my controller or in my routes? because i have a select box and i want to filter something thats why i want to store it in variables

Comment: and where do you get the user_id? i dont have this

Comment: @MonaMuhr it's just an example my dude, I think problem causes from your route. As I know laravel doesn't support dynmaic route names and all special characters in routes.. your route is `Route::post('user/{$stellentyp}', 'StartController@getValues')->name('user.{$stellentyp}');
` but it should be like `Route::post('user/{stellentyp}', 'StartController@getValues')->name('user.stellentyp');
`

Answer (score 0):

Route : -

```
Route::post('user/{stellentyp}', 'StartController@getValues');
```

Controller : -

```
public function getValues(Request $request,$stellentyp=''){
 $typ=$request->get('typ');
 $stellentyp=$request->get('stellentyp');
 $bereich=$request->get('bereich');
 $view = 'user.'.$stellentyp;
 return view($view,['typ' => $typ, 'stellentyp', $stellentyp, 'bereich', $bereich]);
}
```

Use this code to get the expected answer.